# manage-bde GET fails for one drive

Tags: bitlocker

I have 5 `bitlocker`-encrypted drives on my PC: C, D, E, F, G

I can run the following commands successfully to obtain the bitlocker recovery key:

```
manage-bde -protectors C: -get
manage-bde -protectors E: -get
manage-bde -protectors F: -get
manage-bde -protectors G: -get
```

But the D-drive command fails:

```
manage-bde -protectors D: -get
```

Error:

```
Volume D: [DATA]
All Key Protectors

ERROR: An error occurred (code 0x80070490):
Element not found.
```

There is nothing special about my D drive. It is an internal SSD just like C and G. My E and F drives are both external USB SSD drives.

I can go into the bitlocker UI in Win10 and get the recovery key for D with no problem; it only fails from the command line, even though all others succeed. (Yes, I launched the windows command shell as Admin.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decrypted and re-encrypted the drive with bitlocker and that solved the problem.